# How to Change WinForms Button Color?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

I have made 2 buttons inside of a WinForms `DataGridView`, and now I'd like to change the color of the buttons and set their caption. I looked, but could not find a property to do this; can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you provide the code sample, or specifics of "made 2 button inside DataGridView"??

Comment: This is what happens when you don't properly tag and document your question.  The odds of getting a usable answer are low.

Comment: The right direction would be showing what you have done, it would be a valuable insight for getting any relevant answer down here

Answer (score 6):

If it's WPF you can do

```
 <Button x:Name="Button1" Background="Red" Content="Click Me" />
```

if it's winforms, you can set BackColor and Text from property grid or from code you could do

```
button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
button1.Text = "Click Me";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not [Color.FromArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

```
Button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Caption">
    <asp:ControlStyle ForeColor="Red" BackgroundColor="Blue />
</asp:ButtonField>
```